# Two method code that prints an array of 1-20 with a span of 10

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The following needs to be in the main method:

1. Declare an array of size 20 that will contain 20 integers.
2. Generate 20 random integers with a range of 1 to 10 and place them into this array.
3. Use a FOR loop that will run from 1 to 20 to fill the array.
   Within the FOR loop, call Method 1 to generate one random number at a time as you place it in the array.
4. Send the method the beginning value of the range.
5. Send the method the ending value of the range.
6. Display the contents of the array.
7. Call Method 2 to print out the array.
8. Send the method the array.
9. Send the method the size of the array.

Here is my code so far, getting a few errors:

```
Kidwell_Lab09.java:29: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int randomNumbers = new int[SIZE]; 
Kidwell_Lab09.java:32: error: array required, but int found System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
Kidwell_Lab09.java:39: error: cannot find symbol x = inputReader.nextInt();
symbol: variable x location: class Kidwell_Lab09
Kidwell_Lab09.java:40: error: cannot find symbol } while (x == 1); 
symbol: variable x location: class Kidwell_Lab09 4 errors
```

At this pint, I feel a bit lost, thanks in advance:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public final class  {
    public static Random generator = new Random();

    public int createNum(int[] randomNumbers, int SIZE, int n, int i) {

        int x;
        SIZE = 20;
        randomNumbers = new int[SIZE];

        Random generator = new Random();
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            n = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;   
            randomNumbers[i] = n;
        }
        return n;
    }

    public void print(int i, int randomNumbers, int SIZE){
        SIZE = 20;
        randomNumbers = new int[SIZE];

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        do{
            Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Do you wish to restart the program, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");            
            x = inputReader.nextInt();
        } while (x == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If you want help, indent your code, and **tell what the errors are**. You don't go to a doctor just saying "here's my body, it sometimes hurts. Oh, and sorry if I didn't have a shower for 4 weeks".

Comment: Kidwell_Lab09.java:29: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
        randomNumbers = new int[SIZE];
                        ^
Kidwell_Lab09.java:32: error: array required, but int found
            System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
                                                                    ^
Kidwell_Lab09.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        x = inputReader.nextInt();
        ^
  symbol:   variable x
  location: class Kidwell_Lab09

Comment: Kidwell_Lab09.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    } while (x == 1);
             ^
  symbol:   variable x
  location: class Kidwell_Lab09
4 errors

Comment: @markspace thanks for taking a look

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks for taking a look as well

Comment: Post the required information in the question, not in comments. And indent your code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *instructions* seem clear enough to me, let's start with `method1`; you're to pass in the start of the range and the end of the range and return a random value between those two values. You have a `Random`, so let's use it. Something like,

```
private static Random generator = new Random();
public static int method1(int start, int end) {
    return generator.nextInt(1 + end - start) + start;
}
```

Next, you need to pass an array and it's length to `method2` (for displaying the array). Here is one such way to do so (I expect your instructor anticipates the use of a `for` loop here, but I'll leave that as an exercise)

```
public static void method2(int[] arr, int len) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Finally, your `main` method should invoke methods `method1` and `method2` to fill the array and to display it. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = method1(1, 10);
    }
    method2(arr, arr.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared unused variables and passing unnecessary variables.

It can be done easily by declaring the `Array` inside the main and then passing just the array in the two functions. You need not to pass the `SIZE` and other variables.

Here is the code snippet:

```
class Main {
    private static final Random RND_GEN = new Random();
    private void createNum(int[] randomNumbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
            randomNumbers[i] = RND_GEN.nextInt(10) + 1;
        }
    }

    private void printNum(int[] randomNumbers){
        for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number " + i + " : " + randomNumbers[i]);
        }
    }

    private void run() {
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1;
        do {
            int[] number = new int[20];
            createNum(number);
            printNum(number);
            System.out.print("Restart Program?, Enter 1 for YES, 2 for NO: ");            
            x = inputReader.nextInt();
        } while (x == 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main me = new Main();
        me.run();
    }
}
```

Input:

```
2
```

Output:

```
Number 0 : 4
Number 1 : 4
Number 2 : 2
Number 3 : 2
Number 4 : 6
Number 5 : 1
Number 6 : 2
Number 7 : 7
Number 8 : 9
Number 9 : 8
Number 10 : 5
Number 11 : 2
Number 12 : 9
Number 13 : 1
Number 14 : 10
Number 15 : 6
Number 16 : 8
Number 17 : 1
Number 18 : 2
Number 19 : 6
```